# Ajax not working in webview android (Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function)

Tags: android

I am trying to call ajax from android webview and it's not working. I am getting this error in console window

```
08-29 12:28:16.411: E/CONTENT(14146): [object Object] @ 1: http://loconav.com/assets/m/history_selector-1b620f001e31e9dfeff6981b3ee9b290.js
08-29 12:28:16.536: E/CONTENT(14146): Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function @ 1: http://loconav.com/assets/m/history_selector-1b620f001e31e9dfeff6981b3ee9b290.js
08-29 12:28:16.683: E/CONTENT(14146): Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function @ 1: http://loconav.com/assets/m/history_selector-1b620f001e31e9dfeff6981b3ee9b290.js
08-29 12:28:16.883: E/CONTENT(14146): Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function @ 1: http://loconav.com/assets/m/history_selector-1b620f001e31e9dfeff6981b3ee9b290.js
08-29 12:28:17.202: E/CONTENT(14146): Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function @ 1: http://loconav.com/assets/m/history_selector-1b620f001e31e9dfeff6981b3ee9b290.js
```

I am using this android code

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
            
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                dialog.show();
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.equals("http://xyz")){
                    editor.putString("login", "true");
                    editor.commit();
                    trytologin = false;
                }else if(url.equals("http://xyz")){
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(WebActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    if(trytologin == true){
                        intent.putExtra("login", "failed");
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
                    alertDialog();
                    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                //pd.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
             @Override
                public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm)
                {
                    Log.e("CONTENT", String.format("%s @ %d: %s", 
                                cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId()));
                    return true;
                }
        });
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I am trying to call this ajax file

```
function GoogleFetchAndFillHistoryLocation(t,e,n,o){$.ajax({url:"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+t+","+e,success:function(t){var e=[],c="",r="";t.results[0].address_components.forEach(function(t,n,o){"Unnamed Road"!=t.long_name&&e.push(t.long_name),t.types.includes("sublocality")&&(c=t.long_name),t.types.includes("locality")&&(r=t.long_name)}),console.log(t.results[0].formatted_address);var i=e.join(", "),a=c+", "+r;o.html(i),n.html(a)},error:function(t){o.html("Some error occurred while fetching address")}})}function HistorySelector(t){this.$selector=t}!function(t){"use strict";var e=function(t,n){var o=/[^\w\-\.:]/.test(t)?new Function(e.arg+",tmpl","var _e=tmpl.encode"+e.helper+",_s='"+t.replace(e.regexp,e.func)+"';return _s;"):e.cache[t]=e.cache[t]||e(e.load(t));return n?o(n,e):function(t){return o(t,e)}};e.cache={},e.load=function(t){return document.getElementById(t).innerHTML},e.regexp=/([\s'\\])(?!(?:[^{]|\{(?!%))*%\})|(?:\{%(=|#)([\s\S]+?)%\})|(\{%)|(%\})/g,e.func=function(t,e,n,o,c,r){return e?{"\n":"\\n","\r":"\\r","    ":"\\t"," ":" "}[e]||"\\"+e:n?"="===n?"'+_e("+o+")+'":"'+("+o+"==null?'':"+o+")+'":c?"';":r?"_s+='":void 0},e.encReg=/[<>&"'\x00]/g,e.encMap={"<":"&lt;",">":"&gt;","&":"&amp;",'"':"&quot;","'":"&#39;"},e.encode=function(t){return(null==t?"":""+t).replace(e.encReg,function(t){return e.encMap[t]||""})},e.arg="o",e.helper=",print=function(s,e){_s+=e?(s==null?'':s):_e(s);},include=function(s,d){_s+=tmpl(s,d);}","function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return e}):t.tmpl=e}(this),HistorySelector.prototype.bindEvents=function(){var t=this;this.$selector.on("change",function(){t.fetchData()})},HistorySelector.prototype.fetchData=function(){$.ajax({context:this,url:this.$selector.data("url"),data:{profiles:{interval:this.$selector.val()}},headers:{"X-Auth-Token":$("#auth-token").data("token")},success:function(t){console.log(t),this.populateData(t),$(".location-panel").each(function(t,e){var n=$(e);setTimeout(function(){GoogleFetchAndFillHistoryLocation(n.data("lat"),n.data("long"),n.find(".short-location"),n.find(".formatted-address"))},200*t)})},error:function(t){console.log(t)}})},HistorySelector.prototype.populateData=function(t){var e=$(tmpl("history-locations",t).trim());$(".history-locations").empty().append(e),$("body").scrollTop()<180&&$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:"180vh"},"slow")},HistorySelector.prototype.init=function(){},$(function(){$(".selectors input").each(function(){var t=new HistorySelector($(this));t.init(),t.bindEvents()})});
```

you can see the ajax file on this link as well - http://www.loconav.com/assets/m/history_selector-1b620f001e31e9dfeff6981b3ee9b290.js

I am using this html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Babatrucks</title>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="lNJn5/GLbnS0cgUYjalFUT+UsgCcDckhWHcqI32OeJ0=" name="csrf-token" />

    <link href="/assets/application-33b3164661d3b2d630f9cbc88419feb4.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/m_application-9613cb73f45d486ef514a74fa1964a46.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/assets/application-95d8b0297f927b393dd0e1aaf163bc4d.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <link href="/assets/m/trucks/show-bcd1a590d01e03df2a78b4c5dbd1a975.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/m/history_selector-1b620f001e31e9dfeff6981b3ee9b290.js"></script>
<div class="row top-bar">
  <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
    <a class="back-arrow" href="/m/trucks">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 text-center title">
    NL 01L 2273
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <iframe class='locate-map' src="/m/trucks/296/locate"></iframe>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="selectors rohan-container">
        <ul class="backline">
          <hr class="rohan-hr">
          <li>
            <label for="profiles_interval_1">1 hours</label>
            <!-- <input type="radio" id="f-option" name="selector"> -->
            <input data-url="http://www.example.com/" id="profiles_interval_1" name="profiles[interval]" type="radio" value="1" />
            <div class="check"></div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <label for="profiles_interval_6">6 hours</label>
            <!-- <input type="radio" id="s-option" name="selector"> -->
            <input data-url="http://www.example.com/" id="profiles_interval_6" name="profiles[interval]" type="radio" value="6" />
            <div class="check">
              <div class="inside"></div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <label for="profiles_interval_24">24 hours</label>
            <!-- <input type="radio" id="t-option" name="selector"> -->
            <input data-url="http://www.example.com/" id="profiles_interval_24" name="profiles[interval]" type="radio" value="24" />
            <div class="check">
              <div class="inside"></div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- rohan ends -->
    </div>
    <div class="row history">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="history-locations col-xs-12"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="auth-token" data-token=""></div>
<script src="/assets/timeline/modernizr-04ac4151e53119ba85cdc7679379cd0d.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="history-locations">
  <section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">
    {% for (var i = 0; i < o['profiles'].length; i++) { %}
      <div class="cd-timeline-block location-panel" data-lat="{%= o['profiles'][i]['lat'] %}" data-long="{%= o['profiles'][i]['long'] %}">
        <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
          <img alt="Picture" src="/assets/timeline/cd-icon-location-20955b176b47169a313e3c8c11803cc1.svg" />
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

        <div class="cd-timeline-content">
          <h2 class="">{%= o['profiles'][i]['actual_received_at'] %}</h2>
          <p class="formatted-address"></p>
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
      </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->
    {% } %}
  </section>
</script>
<script src="/assets/timeline/main-f1dcfd5d7be80e6258f34c7dded2ee86.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function FetchAndFillLocation(lat, long, infoDiv, truckNumber, speed) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var method = 'GET';
    var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='
              + lat
              + ','
              + long
              + '&sensor=true';
    var async = true;
    request.open(method, url, async);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        var address = data.results[0];
        infoDiv.empty();
        infoDiv.append('<div class="info-box-title"><span class="left-align-number"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> '+ truckNumber +'</span><span class="right-align-speed"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> ' + speed + ' Km/h</span></div><div class="info-box-text">' + address.formatted_address + '</div>');
      }
    };
    request.send();
  }

  function UpdateMarkerPosition(current_location_div) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var method = 'GET';
    var url = '/api/v1/trucks/location?truck[slug]=abc';
    var async = true;
    request.open(method, url, async);
    request.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token', 'abc');
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(request.readyState == 4){
        if(request.status == 200) {
          var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText).current_cordinate;
          var truckCords = { lat: data.lat, lng: data.long }
          FetchAndFillLocation(truckCords.lat, truckCords.lng, current_location_div, data.key, data.speed);
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
          UpdateMarkerPosition(current_location_div)
        }, 10000);
      }
    };
    request.send();
  }
  $(function() {
    UpdateMarkerPosition($('.current-location'));
  })
</script>
        </div>
      </div><!--/row-->

      <footer>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-81486803-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that a lot of individual files don't end their code with a semicolon. Most `jQuery` scripts end with `(jQuery)` and you need to have `(jQuery);`.

Consider adding `jquery` locally or via a `CDN`.